# java android listView set diffrent background color and selected item

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to set diffrent background color in my lit view in adapter I did this

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkGrey));
            } else {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            }
```

and it works but when I added this :

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
```

here :

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomPanel" />
```

I didn't see a selected item but when I remove a setting color in my adapter I see a selected item

Comment: You have take a variable in pojo list item class and set background based on that variable values.

Comment: You should add `list_selector.xml` to the ListView item.And as background.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal I don't understand you

Comment: @KeLiuyue I added list_selector.xml to listView

Comment: I meant that you added it to the ListView's item.@DheerubhaiBansal

Answer (score 2):

you can set background under this method for selected item

```
  myListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: how I can  change a color ?

Comment: i think you just need to call convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorname)) inside onItemSelected